# Remove all characters different from particular characters (i.e., keep a selection)

Tags: r, regex, string, stringr

I'd like to remove all characters that do *not* match a particular set of characters.

For instance, I would like to remove all characters different from the star symbol (*), i.e., keep only the stars.

To remove them, I use the following:

```
s <- "sdf*ses**e"
stringr::str_remove_all(s, "\\*")
```

But how to keep only the stars? I've tried various things (`str_remove_all(s, "!\\*")`, `str_remove_all(s, "-\\*")`), with no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to negate the stars using the circumflex

```
stringr::str_remove_all(s, "[^\\*]")
```

Another possibility using base R

```
gsub("[^*]","",s)
```

Comment: `gsub("[^*]", "", s)` will do it. This answer gives incorrect results if you happen to have a backslash in the string - `gsub("[^\\*]","", "test*string\\")` for instance.

Answer (score 2):

`stringr::str_remove_all(s, "[^\\*]")`